# docker: sed replacement fails only during docker build

Tags: docker, nginx, sed, dockerfile

I'm baffled by this problem.
If I run this:

```
FROM jtreminio/php:8.1
RUN sed -i 's,^\(user \).*,\1'www\;',g'  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I get this error:

```
#0 0.339 sed: can't read /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: No such file or directory
```

But the file is there, and if I run sed from bash or with `docker run`, **it works**:

```
$ docker run jtreminio/php-nginx:8.1 sed -i 's,^\(user \).*,\1'www\;',g'  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                    CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                                              NAMES
97a971771a05   jtreminio/php-nginx:8.1   "sed -i 's,^\\(user \\…"   25 seconds ago   Exited (0) 24 seconds ago                                                                      gifted_nightingale
```

what gives?

---

UPDATE:

```
RUN cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.bak
```

this also fails. It really looks like the file's not there. I suppose it's dynamically generated at start up. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: In your first example, you're using `jtreminio/php`. In your second example, you're using `jtreminio/php-nginx`. It sounds reasonable that you would only find the nginx configuration in the second image.

Comment: that's it! let's say I feel "humbled" :)
post your answer if you'd like me to approve it. Thank you!